# intToStr recursively

Tags: c++, c, arrays, recursion

This is a task from school, I am supposed to write a recursive function that will convert a given int to a string, I know I'm close but I can't point the missing thing in my code, hints are welcome.

```
void intToStr(unsigned int num, char s[])
{
    if (num < 10)
    {   
        s[0] = '0' + num;
    }

    else
    {
        intToStr(num/10, s);
        s[strlen(s)] = '0' + num%10;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** my problem is that the function only works for pre initialized arrays, but if I let the function work on an uninitialized function it will not work.

Comment: If you describe what isn't working with your code, perhaps it would help? [How is s initialized?]

Comment: That's exactly the thing, when s is initialized everything is working excellent, but if s isn't given to the function initialized things are getting messed up. I know it has something to do with the fact I'm not putting \0 at the end of the string but I don't know where should I put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your array is zero-initialized, you are forgetting to append a null terminator when you modify it.

Just add it right after the last character:

```
void intToStr(unsigned int num, char s[])
{
    if (num < 10)
    {   
        s[0] = '0' + num;
        s[1] = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        intToStr(num/10, s);
        s[strlen(s)+1] = 0; //you have to do this operation here, before you overwrite the null terminator
        s[strlen(s)] = '0' + num%10;
    }
}
```

Also, your function is assuming that s has enough space to hold all the digits, so you better make sure it does (INT_MAX is 10 digits long I think, so you need at least 11 characters).

Comment: '\0' and 0 are (for *this* purpose) the same thing.

Comment: I'm allowed to assume that the array is big enough

Answer (score 0):

Andrei Tita already showed you the problem you had with the NULL terminators. I will show you an alternative, so you can compare and contrast different approaches:

```
int intToStr(unsigned int num, char *s)
{   
    // We use this index to keep track of where, in the buffer, we
    // need to output the current character. By default, we write
    // at the first character.
    int idx = 0;

    // If the number we're printing is larger than 10 we recurse
    // and use the returned index when we continue.
    if(num > 9)
        idx = intToStr(num / 10, s);

    // Write our digit at the right position, and increment the
    // position by one. 
    s[idx++] = '0' + (num %10);

    // Write a terminating NULL character at the current position
    // to ensure the string is always NULL-terminated.
    s[idx] = 0;

    // And return the current position in the string to whomever
    // called us.
    return idx;
}
```

You will notice that my alternative also returns the final length of the string that it output into the buffer.

Good luck with your coursework going forward!